# How to use MPI_Gather to send data other process to process root

Tags: c, mpi

I have a problem with MPI_Gather, in the part of the code enclosed in `(rank! = 0)` if  etc ... I inserted the call to `MPI_Gather` as I want to send `worker_clusters` to the root process, i.e. process 0. In the `if (rank == 0)` etc ... I allocated space for `latter_clusters` to be able to store the values ​​sent by `MPI_Ghater`. The problem is that the `latter_clusters` does not store anything. Who can help me and tell me how I can change the code to make it work? Thanks to those who will answer.

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
int rank, size;

MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Datatype POINT;
MPI_Type_contiguous(2, MPI_DOUBLE, &POINT);
MPI_Type_commit(&POINT);

int num_clusters = 2;
int num_points = 9;
int job_size = 0;
int* latter_clusters;
int* worker_clusters;
int job_done = 0;

Point* centroids = calloc(sizeof(Point), num_clusters);
Point* points;
Point* buffreceive;

if (rank == 0) {
        //there are code to read a file the points
        //.....
    latter_clusters=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*num_points);
    centroids = calloc(sizeof(Point), num_clusters);
    initialize(centroids, num_clusters);

    do
    {
        for(int i=0; i<num_points; i++)
            printf("slave_clusters %d\n",latter_clusters[i]);

    }while(job_done);
}

MPI_Bcast(&num_clusters, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(centroids, num_clusters, POINT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

buffreceive = malloc(sizeof(Point) * job_size);
MPI_Scatter(points, job_size, POINT, buffreceive, job_size, POINT, 0,
        MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if (rank != 0) {

    worker_clusters=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*job_size);

    do
    {
        printf("Calculation of new clusters [%d]\n",rank);
        for (int i = 0; i < job_size; i++) {
            int cluster = 0;
            double distance = 0;
            double min_distance = (pow(
                    (buffreceive[i].x - centroids[0].x) * 100, 2)
                    + pow((buffreceive[i].y - centroids[0].y) * 100, 2));

            for (int j = 1; j < num_clusters; j++) {
                distance = pow((buffreceive[i].x - centroids[j].x) * 100, 2)
                        + pow((buffreceive[i].y - centroids[j].y) * 100, 2);
                if (distance <= min_distance) {
                    cluster = j;
                    min_distance = distance;
                }
            }
            worker_clusters[i] = cluster;
        }

        MPI_Gather(worker_clusters, job_size, MPI_INT, latter_clusters,job_size, MPI_INT,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }while(job_done);
}

MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `MPI_Gather()` is a collective operation, so it must be invoked by **all** the ranks of the communicator. In this case, rank `0` must also call `MPI_Gather()`.

Comment: As a side note, you must make sure all the ranks have the same value for `job_done`.